# Eclipse RCP: Dependencies correct (?) but get a NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a RCP project where I cannot fix a NoClassDefFoundError: One plugin depends on another plugin. The plugin-dependencies are set in the manifest, packages exported, and there is no error at compile time. Both plugins are in the product dependencies and visible in the installation details of the product.

But when I run the application I get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when the one plugin wants to use a class from the other plugin.

Any hints how to find the reason for this are greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: The error occurs with all classes from the other plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem: I created the plugin which could not be loaded from an existing Java project. And somehow I deleted the "." in the entry Bundle-classpath in the plugin manifest (the plugin has some jars which -> so lib/xyz.jar was in the Bundle-classpath entry but not the ".").

For the class-loader of the bundle the "." means to search for classes from the root path of the bundle (or something like that), so it could not find the classes. However, there were no errors in the IDE so it was hard to find.

Comment: That little dot kept me 3 days searching, thanks for your answer, I'm finally there.

Answer (score 1):

Is the configuration for running the application correct i.e. all dependencies are also put in the running configuration?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I added all dependencies in the product configuration, so this should be correct.